# upload excel files in gui and save them as df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I'm working on a code which work with severals excel file that I uploaded manually or by their path.
I now want to create a gui which enable the user to upload differents excel files, save them as dataframes and enable me to use them and manipulate them.
The user has to click on a button to upload the files, a button for each file.
The problem is that I don't manage to save the files in df that I can use outside of the function.

I would like your help.
Thanks

I tried this

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("File Uploader")

df = None

# Create a function to open a file selection dialog and read the selected file into a dataframe
def open_file():
    # Open the file selection dialog
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    # Read the file into a dataframe
    global df
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

button = tk.Button(text="Select File", command=open_file)
button.pack()
print(df)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can make a function to manage what you want to do in `df` and call it at the end of `open_file()` function

```
def open_file():
    # Open the file selection dialog
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    # Read the file into a dataframe
    global df
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    print_df()

def print_df():
    print(df)
```